# Having problems with photos appearance

Tags: website-design

I am having some trouble designing the following web page. I somehow do not like the way the big photos are presented in the project. Can anyone suggest an idea how to improve the general look of this images block..? Would be great.

I guess, this question can be *answered*, not just *discussed*, for example by giving some inspiration projects or giving specific design hints.

The 2nd image is smaller because it was cropped for the screenshot.
I like big images which are place this way. Sliders are boring. Look e.g. here: http://www.spotify.com, they have also big pictures and it looks great.

It is not easy to say, what I exactly don't like. It is the general look. Maybe because the pictures are not so good and professional and I am looking for a better way to present them.

[image: Project]

Comment: Could you elaborate, without interactivity its hard to get a feel for it. I mean is the bottom image actually smaller then the top or was it cropped just on this screenshot? Is there a reason they're so large and if so then why not as an image slider? What specifically do you not like about the image blocks? I'd suggest looking over this for help on making a good critique question, then edit yours with a bit more info: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/672/guidelines-for-critique-questions

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit there's a few things I could suggestion:

**1.** 
Enlarge the second image slightly so the computer display goes to the edge. The gray of the monitor blends in with your background causing the alignment to look sloppy. This is the area I'm referring to:

[image: Computer Screen]

**2.** The font on the image captions is a handwritten font which doesn't match the menu or logo at all. You should probably use a more modern sans-serif font to stay consistent in the overall feel.

**3.** There needs to be negative space to allow viewers to focus on a single image at any given time. Whether you do this by adding text between, or design elements between, or interface elements.

The Spotify example works because in between each large element there's substance. The exact style Spotify is using is referred to as [Parallax Scrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling). We've had a few questions on here about it -

[Search: Parallax on GraphicDesign.StackExchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=parallax).

A search engine can find plenty more examples and tutorials that will help you, here's one nice tutorial site to get you started:

[Tutsplus: A Simple Parallax Scrolling Technique](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-parallax-scrolling-technique--net-27641)

Comment: Ok, thanks man.... +1 for you. Maybe someone has more suggestions. The hand writing font is consequently used in the project on other places - of course you couldn't have known it, but I guess it doesn't match anyhow...